# Objects are not valid as a React child (React Navigation)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `React Navigation`, I want to add right button in `StackNavigator`. After adding right button, I get such error:

> Object is not valid as React child (found: object with keys {right}).
>   If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

How to fix that error?

Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

class ReviewScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Review Jobs',
      header: () => {
          return {
              right: <Text>Go right</Text> 
          };
      }
  }

    render (){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>ReviewScreen</Text>
            </View>


        );
    }
}

export default ReviewScreen;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `header`. `header` expects a React Component that represents the whole header, not a plain object. Use `headerRight`:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Review Jobs',
  headerRight: <Text>Go right</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't render an object in the header options. You are returning an object instead of the text tag. Just change your code as below to make it working:-

```
      headerRight:<Text>Go right</Text>
```

instead of :-

```
      header: () => {
      return {
          right: <Text>Go right</Text> 
      };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`headerRight`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#headerRight) prop to set your header's right button to a custom one.

**Example**

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Review Jobs',
  headerRight:<Text>Go right</Text>
}
```